# TypeScript - Extract interface fields from any obejct

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to extract only interface fields from an object
I saw there is a way to do that with 'as' keyword, but it's not working for me

I tried:

```
let data = {
    name: "toto",
    age: 10
}

interface Human {
    name: string;
}


let p = data as Human

console.log(p)
```

but i got:

```
[LOG]: {
  "name": "toto",
  "age": 10
}
```

is there any way to just get:

```
[LOG]: {
    name: "toto"
}
```

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

No, this won't work this way. With `as` you only tell the compiler that you are sure wich type of object it is. But you do not automatically put aside unwanted fields that do not match the interface.

This is one way to do it properly:

```
interface IHuman {
    name: string;
}

class Human implements IHuman {
    constructor(public name: string) {}
}

let human: IHuman = new Human(data.name);
```